# How to index ndarray in tuple using boolean with Numpy Python?

Tags: numpy, indexing, boolean-operations

I would like to index `ndarray` in a `tuple` using a `boolean mask` such as below

```
import numpy as np
n_max = 5
list_no = np.arange ( 0, n_max )
lateral = np.tril_indices ( n_max, -1 )
mask= np.diff ( lateral [0].astype ( int ) )
mask [-1] = 1
Expected=lateral[mask!= 0]
```

However, when executing the line `Expected=lateral[mask!= 0]`,
the compiler return an error

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

```
Expected=
0 = {ndarray: (4,)} [1 2 3 4]
1 = {ndarray: (4,)} [0 1 2 3]
```

May I know where did I do wrong?

Comment: May you tell us where the occurs? (The traceback)

Comment: @hpaulj, I have edited the thread, but to answer your question the error occur at the last line `lateral[mask!-0]`

Comment: Tell us about `lateral`.  You could even show the whole thing!  Be generkus with the information.  Good answers show results.

Comment: It is a 2D coordinate. and I would like to extract certain 2D coordinate if it fulfill the boolean condition. I hope this answer this your question @hpaulj

Comment: No.  From the docs I see it is a tuple.  We index a tuple with a simple number.  a boolean array works on arrays, not tuples.

Comment: Any suggestion on what modification I should do, if indexing using boolean is not possible @hpaulj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like the size of the mask and lateral[0] are different. Since mask is the difference between each element in the array, it is of size n-1 when lateral[0] is of size n. You might want to append to the mask array instead.
Also, since lateral is a tuple, you would need to index on the tuple before applying the mask.

You might be need something like this:

```
import numpy as np
n_max = 5
list_no = np.arange(0, n_max)
lateral = np.tril_indices(n_max, -1)
mask = np.diff(lateral[0].astype(int))
mask = np.append(mask, 1)
expected_0 = lateral[0][mask != 0]
print(expected_0)
expected_1 = lateral[1][mask != 0]
print(expected_1)
```